# How to encrypt a file so that only someone with the key can read it, not even the person who used the program to produce the file, using C#/.Net?

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm looking for a way to encrypt a file so that it can only be read by people in possession of the key. This does not necessarily include the person running the program that produces the file.

Let me give you an example to make it a bit more clear. Suppose you had a quiz program that a student would use. After the student completed the task I would like to save and possibly analyze the results. Then I want to save the given answers and the analysis to a file and encrypt it in a way that neither the student, nor anyone snooping can decrypt the file. Only someone in possession of the right key or password should be able to read it. In this case perhaps the teacher. However, this is just an example, the actual data may or may not be a lot more complex than a few booleans. It may contain actual text, whole instances of classes or even pictures. In case that matters.

All solutions I could come up with involved doing something to the data before saving it, like perhaps scrambling the byte array or something. However, anyone who would in any way get access to the source code would see how it was done and so can easily reverse it, which is of course not useful.
So I'm not even sure if this is really possible or if so, what it's called. Because of that, I don't know if this question has been asked before, as I don't know what I'd even search for to find out.

Any ideas? Preferably of course something built in to .NET, as I trust Microsoft a lot more with this than myself...

Comment: Use asymmetric encryption such as RSA. Student encrypts with the public key, private key is used to decrypt.

Comment: If people can see the source, you'll have a hard time. You _can_ encrypt for a recipient (using async encryption with a public/private key pair), but you seem to dislike that idea. If that isn't enough, I doubt that you can do what you want. (If this is really about students and a student can cheat by disassembling your application and ~fixing~ the score, you should give said student an A, I'd say)

Comment: What makes you think I'd dislike that idea? I've done a bit of research now, using the lingo you guys taught me. And while there certainly is a lot to learn to get it right, asymmetric encryption looks like it's exactly what I want, no? Or rather, a hybrid encryption. Which I'm still trying to get my head around...

Answer (score 3):

You are just talking about basic asymmetric public key technology. One key can only be used for encryption one key can only be used for decryption. Any class that derives from [`System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) would be able to do it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! After reading a bit about that it appears like that's exactly what I need. If I understood it correctly I could even "hardcode" the public keys in, yes? So that a student might just select their teacher and the program automatically uses the corresponding public key. That's terrific, way easier than I imagined. How secure is this though? From what I read it seems like it's "believed" to be impossible to be cracked. Is that true? Without someone getting access to the private key, of course.

Comment: Well if it is not true you can't trust https websites, because that is what that is doing. The "Certificate" you get from a website holds the public key for doing the asymmetric encryption you use to transmit data securly to the website. Just make sure you do your learning before you set it up so you set all the configuration options correctly so you don't accidentally set up a weak encryption setup.

Comment: How secure it is comes down to key length and how you handle the keys (and also that the algorithm is implemented properly - why it's best to use encryption code written by experts!). "Impossible to crack" is a bit strong though, it's more about being impossible in any realistic time frame without getting exceedingly lucky. Https internet traffic is secured using this kind of encryption, with 2048 bit keys being the standard. The public key and private key are mathematically linked, how you distribute them is the hard part.